# Running signalR in OwinHost

Tags: signalr, owin, signalr-hub, katana

I created a new Empty Project in VS 2013, configured it to run using OwinHost and installed the following packages in order:

```
PM> Install-Package Owinhost
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS
PM> Update-Package jQuery
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin
```

Then, I added a Hub class as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace OwinHosting
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }   
    } 
}
```

In the startup.cs I added this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OwinHosting.Startup))]
namespace OwinHosting
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           var config = new HubConfiguration {EnableCrossDomain = true };
           app.MapHubs(config);

            app.UseStaticFiles("/Web");
         }
     }
 }
```

Finally, I added a Web folder, moved the Scripts folder to it and added the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        background-color: #99CCFF;
        border: thick solid #808080;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
</div>

<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="http://localhost:8888/signalr/hubs"></script>

<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Set the hubs URL for the connection
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8888/signalr";

        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.myHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run the page, it asks for the "username". When I type a message and hit "send", it just doesn't respond with anything.

I used Chrome Tools, it seems "chat" variable inside the "click" event is undefined for some reason.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you don't have the right NuGet packages installed.

The reason your chat `chat` variable is undefined is likely because your `http://localhost:8888/signalr/hubs` script is not being found, and that script is responsible for defining `$.connection.myHub`.

Since you are using the latest version (2.0.3) of the SignalR JS client, you should also be using the latest SignalR server components. The [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin/1.2.1) package you installed no longer exists in SignalR 2.x.x. The latest Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin package actually depends on Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.2.1 which is out of date.

The easiest way to get started self-hosting SignalR, would probably be to uninstall all your SignalR and Owin related packages and follow this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

This tutorial is based on using the [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost) which depends on Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost instead of OwinHost.

It's very important that you install the Microsoft.Owin.Cors package and call `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` like in the tutorial since the `HubConfiguration.EnableCrossDomain` property no longer exits.